# Error in completely unchanged source code

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

I'm resuming work on an Angular app that I started as an intern about 12 months ago.
There were previously no errors that I am now experiencing. Now when I clone the repository onto my new computer, and even my old computer on which I originally developed the app, I'm receiving the following errors:

`(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function`

`Failed to instantiate module app due to`
`Error: [$injector:modulerr]`
`Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:`
`Module 'ngSanitize' is not available`

`bower.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.4.7",
  "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
  "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
  "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
  "checklist-model": "~0.6.0",
  "font-awesome": "fontawesome#~4.4.0",
  "ngSignaturePad": "*",
  "signature_pad": "~1.5.1",
  "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "latest",
  "moment": "~2.10.6",
  "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.7",
  "ui-select": "angular-ui-select#~0.13.2",
  "angular-touch": "~1.4.7",
  "angular-ui-grid": "~3.0.7",
  "angular-spinner": "~0.8.0",
  "angularPrint": "angular-print#~0.3.8",
  "lodash": "~4.13.1"
},
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "~1.4.7"
}
```

The `ngSanitize` module is included in the `gulpfile` for js dependencies and declared in `angular.module`.

```
gulp.task('js-deps', function () {
gulp.src([
    './public/bower_components/moment/moment.js',
    './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    './public/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/checklist-model/checklist-model.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/signature_pad/signature_pad.js',
    './public/bower_components/ngSignaturePad/ngSignaturePad.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/spin.js/spin.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.min.js',
    './public/bower_components/angularPrint/angularPrint.js'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('deps.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
```

angular-sanitize.min.js.map is also included

```
gulp.src([
    './public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js.map',
    './public/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js.map',
    './public/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js.map'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
```

Angular module

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'checklist-model',
    'ngSignaturePad',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.select',
    'ngTouch',
    'angularSpinner',
    'AngularPrint'
  ])
```

*The good thing is that I've learned a great lesson on the importance of capturing my environment with tools like Docker and vagrant files.*

I'm trying to think about what was different between when I first developed the app and now.

On my old computer I have since updated `npm`, `nodejs`, and possibly, but I'm not certain, `gulp -g`, and `bower -g`.

I don't think there is an issue with `npm` or `nodejs` because the problem is not with the server or npm dependencies. I can start up the server just fine. The error shows up in the browser console. The problem may be with how `gulp` is building code bundle.

I've tried installing older versions of each of these, reinstalling dependencies, and then rebuilding code, to no avail.

I can see the dependency code bundle with `ngSanitize` but I don't know what to look for if there is an error in the build.

Where do I look for the next clue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to my mentor, Greg, for helping me to figure this out.

This error is obscure and the solution doesn't shed light on why all this happened but here it is:

Everything after `ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker`fails.

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.router',,
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'checklist-model',
    'ngSignaturePad',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.select',
    'ngTouch',
    'angularSpinner',
    'AngularPrint'
  ])
```

If I comment out `ngSanitize`, then `ui.select` fails, so on and so forth.

If I add a semicolon to the end of the `datetimepicker.js` file, the build works and error is no more. A relief, yet still frustrating.

For anyone else with this same problem, here's how I modified my `gulpfile` to add in the needed `;`.

`npm install --save gulp-insert`

Require `gulp-insert` in gulpfile

Add `.pipe(insert.append(';'))` before file concatenation occurs

```
  var insert = require('gulp-insert');
  ...
  ...
  './public/bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.min.js',
  './public/bower_components/angularPrint/angularPrint.js'
])
.pipe(insert.append(';'))
.pipe(concat('deps.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
```